# RPI4: sleep 10 waits 43 seconds when CPU underclocked

Tags: pi-4, underclocking

I use an under-clocked Rasberry Pi 4 to save power using these settings in `/boot/config.txt`:

```
arm_freq=700
arm_freq_min=100
core_freq=250
core_freq_min=75
sdram_freq=400
over_voltage=0
# source
# https://www.foxplex.com/sites/raspberry-pi-over-und-underclocking/
```

and only 1 cpu (`maxcpus=1` in `/boot/cmdline.txt`). Unfortunately, the shell command `sleep 10` (and the equivalent commands in Python or Julia) now waits 43 seconds instead of 10. Any ideas how this can be corrected?

When the CPU is under-clocked I get these timings (as suggested by @Seamus):

```
pi@drifter02:~ $ date +%M:%S:%N; sleep 10.; date +%M:%S:%N
42:18:636998788
43:21:810109674
pi@drifter02:~ $ date +%M:%S:%N; sleep 10.; date +%M:%S:%N
43:24:804538802
43:34:815360222
pi@drifter02:~ $ date +%M:%S:%N; sleep 10.; date +%M:%S:%N
43:36:331290110
43:46:341481104
pi@drifter02:~ $ date +%M:%S:%N; sleep 10.; date +%M:%S:%N
43:49:616077991
44:54:628062596
```

Even if the the two timestamps of date report 10 s (2nd and 3rd test), it does not correspond to what I see with a stop watch. Or using the time command over ssh, I get more consistent timings (but consistently wrong)

```
$ date +%M:%S:%N; ssh  pi@192.168.0.199 sleep 10.; date +%M:%S:%N;
50:07:581271832
50:34:179524391
$ date +%M:%S:%N; ssh  pi@192.168.0.199 sleep 10.; date +%M:%S:%N;
50:35:132595217
51:07:345482960
$ date +%M:%S:%N; ssh  pi@192.168.0.199 sleep 10.; date +%M:%S:%N;
51:08:313846466
51:36:433839692
$ date +%M:%S:%N; ssh  pi@192.168.0.199 sleep 10.; date +%M:%S:%N;
52:03:028000964
52:37:534952569
```

Just executing `pwd` takes about 0.5 s, so the time it take to make a SSH connection cannot be blamed.

```
$ date +%M:%S:%N; ssh  pi@192.168.0.199 pwd; date +%M:%S:%N;
54:03:634693731
/home/pi
54:04:184457211
```

Without under-clocking, the timings are correct.

More infos:

- Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.5
- Linux 5.15.61-v8+, aarch64
- Debian GNU/Linux 11 (OS reported in `/etc/issue`)
- Installation image: Rapberry Pi OS Lite (64-bit)

Comment: `sleep 2.326` ... is there a command to sleep a number of milliseconds or a number of microseconds?

Comment: @jsotola: Yes - that's it: `sleep 2.326`

Comment: I added the information about the OS. Is there anything else needed? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the option `arm_freq_min=100`. Apparently, lowering this frequency is not supported (and not reducing significantly the power consumption anyways):

> Minimum value of arm_freq used for dynamic frequency clocking. Note
> that reducing this value below the default does not result in any
> significant power savings and is not currently supported.

https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/config_txt.html